# Can Classic and Modern experiences coexist in the same site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, custom-masterpage, modern-experience, classic-experience

I am a bit confused with Modern vs. Classic experiences.

We are migrating a SP2013 on-prem to Online and I am rebuilding the custom code with SPFx web parts or extensions; however, the client developers still want to be able to edit master pages and page layouts with SharePoint Designer using javascript.

1. Can we enable master pages and page layouts customization in just
   some pages or is it a setting for the entire site?
2. Is there a site setting where I can switch from modern to classic
   back and forth?
3. Should I encourage the client developers to embrace SPFx?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can still use the classic publishing infrastructure - even on Group Connected Team Sites. Classic pages and views will use the master page set for the web.
2. Classic pages created with publishing pages will be classic until Microsoft forces us to convert them. This will not happen for a long time, and when it happens you will have a long time (maybe a couple of years?) to prepare for the switch.  The lists (that support modern experience) all have a setting to which mode is the preferred one.
3. **YES**! :-)

Comment: we decided to go with Communication Site template because the layout with no left side navigation and search on top right corner was more similar to what they had. Can we get in trouble because of that? Since it is impossible to activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Communication Site.

Comment: That means you can't reproduce classic pages. You also miss out on all the benefits of having an O365 group connected to the sites.